# Why does switching my logo give me a corrupt PDF file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, adobe, itext

I am creating a PDF file in a ASP.NET C# Windows Console Application, using iTextSharp.

I have this one piece of code. If Site is 'LMH', I get a good PDF i can open with Adobe Reader. If not, I get error: There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document (114).

Here is my code:

```
string ApplicationPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4) { TotalWidth = 800.0F, LockedWidth = true };
float[] widths = new[] { 80.0F, 80.0F, 500.0F, 140.0F };
table.SetWidths(widths);
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
table.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

if (ActiveProfile.Site == "LMH")
{
    Image hmsImage = Image.GetInstance(ApplicationPath + "\\" + "HMS Logo.png");
    hmsImage.ScaleToFit(80.0F, 40.0F);

    PdfPCell hmslogo = new PdfPCell(hmsImage);
    hmslogo.Border = 0;
    hmslogo.FixedHeight = 60;
    table.AddCell(hmslogo);
}
else
{
    Image blankImage = Image.GetInstance(ApplicationPath + "\\" + "emptyLogo.png");
    blankImage.ScaleToFit(80.0F, 40.0F);

    PdfPCell emptyCell = new PdfPCell(blankImage);
    emptyCell.Border = 0;
    emptyCell.FixedHeight = 60;
    table.AddCell(emptyCell);
}
```

And the main trunk:

```
System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(("C:/") + keyPropertyId + ".pdf", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate () , 20, 20, 6, 4);

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, file );

document.AddTitle(_title);
document.Open();
addHeader(document);
addGeneralInfo(document, keyPropertyId);
addAppliances(document, _LGSRobj);
addFaults(document, _LGSRobj);
addAlarms(document, _LGSRobj);
addFinalCheck(document, _LGSRobj);
addSignatures(document, _LGSRobj);
addFooter(document, writer);
document.Close();
writer .Close ();

file.Close();
```

All that has changed is a logo. Both logo files have the same dimensions. What can possibly be wrong? BTW. File opens fine using Foxit, but this is not an acceptable solution.

This is the PDF I can't open with Adobe Reader: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20086858/1003443.pdf

This is the emptyLogo.png file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20086858/emptylogo.png

This is the logo that works: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20086858/HMS%20Logo.png

This is a 'good' version of the pdf with the logo that works: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20086858/1003443-good.pdf

Comment: Can you share the broken PDF in question?

Comment: Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Could you post both images?

Comment: How do I share the PDF and images?

Comment: dropbox is your friend, or any of the other file sharing services.

Comment: Steve: as @KenS says, use a public share on a file sharing service, but please use a service which does not show too many adds or which requires registration.

Comment: I have added the files to dropbox and posted the links on the original question.

Comment: You are using a version of iTextSharp that dates from February 2007. That version has been declared dead years ago. It is no longer supported. Did you try using the most recent iTextSharp version?

Comment: I tried using the latest version I could find, 5.5.3.0. The error persists. BTW. How did you know what version of iTextSharp I used?

Comment: *How did you know what version of iTextSharp I used?* - Well, look at the PDF document properties... ;) And 4.0.1 is really ancient.

Comment: Updating to iTextSharp 5.3.0.0 solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: *Updating to iTextSharp 5.3.0.0 solved the problem* - No. Deleting the already existing target file did. Opening the target file with `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` caused the new PDF (with the small image) to be written over the contents of the PDF with the large image. As it was smaller, though, quite a lot of data from the longer file remained at the end, and this mix-up was not read-able by Adobe Reader.

Comment: I see. I have updated iTextSharp anyway - version 5.5.3.0 (my typo). Is there a better way of preventing this? Maybe FileMode.Create would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very suspicious that both the 'good'  and the not-so-good version have the identical size in spite of very different image sizes. Comparing them one sees that both files differ completely in their first 192993 bytes but from there on only very little. Furthermore the broken PDF contains EOF markers in this region denoting file ends at indices 140338 and 192993 but the following bytes do not at all look like a clean incremental update.

Cutting the file at the first denoted file end, 140338, one gets the file the OP wanted to have.

Thus:

**The code overwrites existing files with new data; if the former file was longer, the remainder of that longer file remains as trash at the end and, therefore, renders the new file broken.**

The OP opens the stream like this:

```
new System.IO.FileStream(("C:/") + keyPropertyId + ".pdf", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

`FileMode.OpenOrCreate` causes the observed behavior.

The `FileMode` values are documented [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx), especially:

- **OpenOrCreate** Specifies that the operating system should open a file if it exists; otherwise, a new file should be created.
- **Create** Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten. ... FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate.

Thus, use

```
new System.IO.FileStream(("C:/") + keyPropertyId + ".pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
```

instead.